# How to add conditions from a variable on Powershell?

Tags: powershell, getcontent

I would like to add an input variable that would allow me to add as many conditions as I want.

Ex : A variable for add `-and ($_ -notmatch '67'`

```
$file = "\Input\27532.csv"
$outFile = "\Output\27532.csv"

$content= Get-Content $file | Where-Object { ($_ -notmatch '24') -and ($_ -notmatch '67')  } | Set-Content $outfile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *single* [`-notmatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-notmatch) operation with [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) *alternation* (`|`), which allows you to pass an open-ended number of substrings:

```
$valuesToExclude = '24', '67', '42'

$content= Get-Content $file | 
  Where-Object { $_ -notmatch ($valuesToExclude -join '|') } | 
   Set-Content $outfile
```

Note: The above assumes that `$valuesToExclude` contains only values that contain no regex *metacharacters* (e.g., `.`); if there's a chance of that, and you want these characters to be interpreted *literally*, call `[regex]::Escape()` on the values:
`($valuesToExclude.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')`